# CSS Grid doesn't work as expected (grid areas)

Tags: css, css-grid

Could somebody help me to figure out why the following example of *CSS Grid* doesn't work as expected? Here's a link into [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Nekto/pen/yPpaBE):

```
.cards {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a a b"
    "c d d"
    "c e e";
}

.card {
  background-color: #1E88E5;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 1.4;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.card1 { grid-area: "a"; }
.card2 { grid-area: "b"; background-color: #4CAF50; }
.card3 { grid-area: "c"; background-color: #FFCA28; }
.card4 { grid-area: "d"; background-color: #F06292; }
.card5 { grid-area: "e"; background-color: #FF8A80; }
```

For some reason grid areas are not properly structured. Probably I forgot something but I couldn't figure out what exactly.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The expected result is to have cards placed in according to the “grid-template-areas” paramether. For example, card #1 should take 2 column cells in the first row, card #4 should include the first column cells of rows 2 and 3, etc.

Comment: Something like this: http://prntscr.com/hc34gn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the *quotation marks* from the `grid-area` *values*:

```
.card1 { grid-area: a; }
.card2 { grid-area: b; background-color: #4CAF50; }
.card3 { grid-area: c; background-color: #FFCA28; }
.card4 { grid-area: d; background-color: #F06292; }
.card5 { grid-area: e; background-color: #FF8A80; }
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 70em;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cards {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a a b"
    "c d d"
    "c e e";
}

.card {
  background-color: #1E88E5;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 1.4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.card1 { grid-area: a; }
.card2 { grid-area: b; background-color: #4CAF50; }
.card3 { grid-area: c; background-color: #FFCA28; }
.card4 { grid-area: d; background-color: #F06292; }
.card5 { grid-area: e; background-color: #FF8A80; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card card1"><h3>Card 1</h3>Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment.</div>
    <div class="card card2"><h3>Card 2</h3>Bring to the table win-win survival strategies to ensure proactive domination. At the end of the day, going forward, a new normal that has evolved from generation X is on the runway heading towards a streamlined cloud solution.</div>
    <div class="card card3"><h3>Card 3</h3>At the end of the day, going forward, a new normal that has evolved from generation X is on the runway heading towards a streamlined cloud solution. User generated content in real-time will have multiple touchpoints for offshoring. Capitalize on low hanging fruit to identify a ballpark value added activity to beta test.</div>
    <div class="card card4"><h3>Card 4</h3>Override the digital divide with additional clickthroughs from DevOps. Nanotechnology immersion along the information highway will close the loop on focusing solely on the bottom line. At the end of the day, going forward, a new normal that has evolved from generation X is on the runway heading towards a streamlined cloud solution.</div>
    <div class="card card5"><h3>Card 5</h3>Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment. Bring to the table win-win survival strategies to ensure proactive domination.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, grid-template-columns becomes useless since grid-template-areas takes over and actually does  the grid layout description  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVprPO

Comment: @G-Cyr, actually, `grid-template-columns` still matters and makes a difference. With `1fr 1fr 1fr` the columns distribute space on the row evenly. Without it, the columns resolve to `auto` width, which renders a different layout.

Comment: @Michael_B Thank you or pointing this out! Yes, I've noticed that the layout becomes changed with and without `grid-template-columns`